# How to use an ethernet port inside a virtual machine with TwinCAT to test IO?

Tags: virtual-machine, twincat

I have a Windows 10 virtual machine with two Ethernet adapters on ESXi. Now I would like to use one ethernet port to simulate my IO. I selected the Ethernet1 adapter, installed the TwinCAT driver on it and after that it showed up under "Installed and ready to use".

[image: install ethernet port]

When I then try to select it as the adapter to use for my IO device, it doesn't show up. This procedure does work for my normal windows installation. Why isn't it working on the virtual machine?

[image: profinet port]

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the later versions of VMware which use the E1000e network driver instead of the E1000 one. The E1000e doesn't work with TwinCAT.

You can select the E1000 adapter type if you select your virtual machine in ESXi and then select Edit. Then select the network adapter you would like to change and select E1000 for the adapter type. Note: to change the adapter type your VM needs to be turned off.

[image: select E1000 adapter type]

You can also change it in the `.vmx` file of your virtual machine. Look for `ethernet0.virtualDev` and set it to `ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000"`.